# How to vertically align images in <td>

Tags: html, css

I got a `<td>` where two images () reside shown as follows. One is much higher than the other. How do I let the shorter one align to the top of `<td />`?

```
<td  style="padding-left: 0px; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: top;">
<img width="85px" src=".../xyz.png"/>
<img src=".../icon_live.gif" /> // shorter one
</td>
```

Comment: Here a solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590933/2736742

Answer (score 24):

You need to set vertical alignment on the images themselves.

```
<style>
td img { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! 

Answer (score 8):

This did the job for me:

```
#logo-table td img, #logo-table td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

In html:

```
 <table id="logo-table">
      <!--table contents with imgs-->
 </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you give a class to your `<img class="tops">` then the CSS

```
.tops {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

will bind the top edge of the images to the table cell top.

Comment: Hmm, the example page that I am looking at right now differs from your sample code in two ways. The img tags have `height=` directives and the style is specified as a class. I am now cross-browser testing...

Comment: Oops, I really meant the `img` tag attribute.

Answer (score 5):

add `align="top"` to the first image (the tall one)

```
<td  style="padding-left: 0px; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: top;">
<img width="85px" src=".../xyz.png" align="top" />
<img src=".../icon_live.gif" /> // shorter one
</td>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need to set it to the smaller one rather than the larger one if you just set one of them.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<td cellpadding="0" valign="top">
  <img width="85" src=".../xyz.png" style="display:inline;"/>
  <img src=".../icon_live.gif" style="display:inline;" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for You:

```
<img style="margin-top:22.5%;" src=".........  />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).